# Task Queues or Multi Threading on google app engine

Tags: python, multithreading, google-app-engine, web2py, task-queue

I have my server on Google App Engine
One of my jobs is to match a huge set of records with another.
This takes very long, if i have to match 10000 records with 100.
Whats the best way of implementing this.

Im, using Web2py stack and deployed my application on Google App Engine.

Answer (score 1):

maybe i'm misunderstanding something, but thos sounds like the perfect match for a task queue, and i can't see how multithreading will help, as i thought this only ment that you can serve many responses simultaneously, it won't help if your responses take longer than the 30 second limit.

With a task you can add it, then process until the time limit, then recreate another task with the remainder of the task if you haven't finished your job by the time limit.

Comment: Its not a web service request. Its a cron job, which executes in regular intervals. So, my major job is to, break down the 1000 comparisons to less and add as tasks to the queue. does that make any sense?

Answer (score 1):

Multithreading your code is not supported on GAE so you can not explicitly use it.

GAE itself can be multithreaded, which means that one frontend instance can handle multiple http requests simultaneously.

In your case, best way to achieve parallel task execution is Task Queue.

Comment: Do you mean that multithreading is not supported in python27 on GAE?

Comment: As of SDK 1.6.4 you can use background threads on backend instances only: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview#background_threads

Answer (score 1):

The basic structure for what you're doing is to have the cron job be responsible for dividing the work into smaller units, and executing each unit with the task queue.  The payload for each task would be information that identifies the entities in the first set (such as a set of keys).  Each task would perform whatever queries are necessary to join the entities in the first set with the entities in the second set, and store intermediate (or perhaps final) results.  You can tweak the payload size and task queue rate until it performs the way you desire.

If the results of each task need to be aggregated, you can have each task record its completion and test for whether all tasks are complete, or just have another job that polls the completion records, to fire off the aggregation.  When the MapReduce feature is more widely available, that will be a framework for performing this kind of work.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIxelKcyCC0
http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/

Comment: Thanks alot. I have gone through the video which you have mentioned about, but i have a question. Doesn't the MapReduce Pipeline make sure of handling large sets of data. Should i need to really break down into smaller chunks of comparison?

Comment: Correct, the MapReduce utility will take care of the chunking and execution.  You provide the map and the reduce.  :)  In my answer above, "dividing the work into smaller units" is what you would do if you were not using MapReduce, but implementing this directly with tasks and an arbitrary amount of data. Thinking of it this way gives you a knob you can turn to tweak performance: the number of records per task. You could create one task for each record, for 10,000 tasks, but that might not be the best use of resources.